# PDO ForEach Loop in array (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to have all results from my database in one array

my function:

```
function GetWinkelProduct($g_Winkel) {
    global $g_Conn;

    $l_Stmt = $g_Conn->prepare("SELECT pd_id FROM `producten_:Winkel`");
    $l_Stmt->bindValue(':Winkel', $g_Winkel, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $l_Stmt->execute();


    $l_qurries = new dbquery();
    $l_LastProduct = $l_qurries->GetLastProduct($g_Winkel);

    while($l_Row = $l_Stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $out = array();

        foreach($l_Row as $product){
            $out[] = $product['pd_id'];
        }
    }
        return $out;        
}
```

other page: `<?php print_r($l_qurries->GetWinkelProduct($g_Winkel)); ?>`

only I get the first result in the array and when I do `$product['pd_id']` I get only the last result.

Comment: no need of foreach loop inside while loop

Comment: You've initialized the array inside the `while` loop.

Comment: @javabrett I deleted the foreach loop though it was needed but only with a while loop it works fine.

Comment: you'r welcome @Erwin !! enjoy!!

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

Change fetch to fetchAll in while loop and renove foreach inside while loop

```
function GetWinkelProduct($g_Winkel) {
    global $g_Conn;

    $l_Stmt = $g_Conn->prepare("SELECT pd_id FROM `producten_:Winkel`");
    $l_Stmt->bindValue(':Winkel', $g_Winkel, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $l_Stmt->execute();


    $l_qurries = new dbquery();
    $l_LastProduct = $l_qurries->GetLastProduct($g_Winkel);

    while($l_Row = $l_Stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $out = array();


            $out[] = $l_Row ['pd_id'];

    }
        return $out;        
}
```

ref:http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize the array outside the while loop and you don't need the foreach.

that way you are creating a new array every time the while iterates, that way you end up replacing the array.

```
    $out = array();    
    while($l_Row = $l_Stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
          $out[] = $l_Row['pd_id'];
    }
    return $out;
```